# SQL Query - Get Name from another table

Tags: mysql

Basically I have 2 tables: `uclk_user` and `uclk_task`

`uclk_user` table has `user_id`, `name`, `postcode`

`uclk_task` table has `user_id`, `job_id`, `description`, `fully_completed`, `date_due`

I want to include the user name from the `uclk_user` in my task query below...
Obviously user_id is the key.

```
select job_id, user_id, fully_completed, description, date_due
from uclk_task
WHERE date_due <= NOW() AND fully_completed = 0
ORDER BY date_due ASC
```

How this should be done?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `JOIN` to select from multiple tables on a common criteria

```
SELECT t.job_id, t.user_id, t.fully_completed, t.description, t.date_due, u.name
FROM uclk_task t
INNER JOIN uckl_user u
ON t.user_id = u.user_id
WHERE t.date_due <= NOW() AND t.fully_completed = 0
ORDER BY t.date_due ASC
```

Comment: Thanks for your fast reply... I have tried your suggestion and seem to get an error...  SQL Error: Column 'user_id' in field list is ambiguous SELECT job_id, user_id, fully_completed, description, date_due
FROM uclk_task
INNER JOIN uclk_user
ON uclk_task.user_id = uclk_user.user_id
WHERE date_due <= NOW() AND fully_completed = 0
ORDER BY date_due ASC

Comment: its better to use alias for tables, and use them for each and every column to avoid future issues. +1 for explicit joins.

Comment: @user1625706: oh yes. My bad, you have to be explicit about which `user_id` column you want to use (either from uckl_user or uckl_task) by prepending the table name or alias

Comment: Very much appreciated. I will use this format in my other queries. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
 select job_id, user_id, fully_completed, description, date_due
    from uclk_task
    Left join
    on date_due <= NOW() AND fully_completed = 0
    ORDER BY date_due ASC
```